# Removing duplicate record text but keeping unique values

Tags: crystal-reports

In our system, it shows each charge as a record, despite the account being the same.

[Crystal reports image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ie9d.jpg)

How would I go about doing this?

Also, is there a way to show it like this even though they are all seperate records?

[Option 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U2yPl.jpg)

Comment: Which one do you need option 1 or option 2

Comment: Actually I think I want it to look like option one. But I added a column if it makes any difference. New image: http://i58.tinypic.com/e7crci.jpg

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this using sub reports.

In main report take distinct record and place the fields `Account` and `city` in detail section.

Now take sub report and place it after the first 2 columns in detail section but take care that you won't select the option distinct records that means you retrieve all records. In sub report place `Charge type, charge` fields

Comment: What you mean by take sub report. Is this the details B section?

Comment: sub report is report inside a report... it is the concept of crystal reports. Its not the detail section B... its the sub report to be placed in detail section B

Comment: By just adding the same charge column to details B, I got the same result it seems.